# REACT - How to call dependent async operations efficient

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, react-hooks

So I have a hook, where I have a method to call statistics by id and a method where I call a list of available statistics.

I want to first of all call the list of statistics and then call the actual statistics data by the id of the first item from the first response. It looks smth. like that:

### hook

```
const useMapStatistics = () => {
  const [selectedStatistics, setSelectedStatistics] = useState(null); // maybe use a useRef here ?
  const [allMapStatistics, setAllMapStatistics] = useState([]);
  const [geoJSON, setGeoJSON] = useState({
    type: "",
    features: [],
  });

  const fetchMapStatisticsById = useCallback((type) => {
      getMapStatisticsById({ type })
        .then((result) => setGeoJSON(result));
    },
    []
  );

  const fetchInitialMapStatistics = useCallback(() => {
    getMapStatisticsList().then((list) => {
        setAllMapStatistics(list.statistics);
        setSelectedStatistics(list.statistics[0]);
        return list.statistics[0];
      })
      .then((type) => fetchMapStatisticsById(type));
  }, [fetchMapStatisticsById]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchInitialMapStatistics();
  }, []);

  return {
    geoJSON,
    allMapStatistics,
    selectedStatistics,
    fetchMapStatisticsById,
    fetchInitialMapStatistics,
  };
};
```

Now Im asking myself if this is the most efficient way on how to execute this? I was also trying  to execute `fetchMapStatisticsById` with the selectedStatistics state like so:

```
  const fetchMapStatisticsById = useCallback(() => {
  getMapStatisticsById({ type: selectedStatistics }) // selectedStatistics is null
    .then(result =>  setGeoJSON(result));
  }, [selectedStatistics]);
```

But this was not working since setting the state in react happens asynchronously (selectedStatistics was null). So Im wondering if it would be better to pass the state for fetching the statistics by id (which was not working for me) or to just pass the statistic id as argument in the useCallback function? There also be the option to put the selectedStatistics within a useRef, which would be changed synchronously. Is that also an option, or is this anti-pattern?

Comment: Just wrap it in a `if (selectedStatistics != null)` to prevent fetching on the initial effect call while the statistic is not yet loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have suggested two ways that gets the job done, and you want to know which is better, it depends on your purpose, because as you are probably wondering they are not the same.

You could do this, but this means that the changing of the map statistics will only happen on initial render when fetchInitialMapStatistics is called. This means that changes to your selectedStatisticsId will not cause the mapStatisits and GeoJSON to change which is not probably what you want.

```
 const fetchInitialMapStatistics = useCallback(() => {
    getMapStatisticsList().then((list) => {
        setAllMapStatistics(list.statistics);
        setSelectedStatistics(list.statistics[0]);
        return list.statistics[0];
      })
      .then((type) => fetchMapStatisticsById(type));
  }, [fetchMapStatisticsById]);
```

on the other hand you could do this, which means anytime the selectedId changes you want to change the geoJSON in state (which is probably what you want), as a side note you should also implement a transition state when the selected id changes, something like a loader.

```
const fetchInitialMapStatistics = useCallback(() => {
    getMapStatisticsList().then((list) => {
        setAllMapStatistics(list.statistics);
        setSelectedStatistics(list.statistics[0]);
        return list.statistics[0];
      })
     
  }, []);

useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedStatistics !== null) {
       // anyway its better here to send the selected id as a param and not take it from state
       // its better for at least three reasons that i can think of now
       // - more readable code
       // - easier code to test
       // - your code is less subject to bugs related to misunderstanding of what the selectedId is
       fetchMapStatisticsById(selectedStatistics);
    }
  }, [selectedStatistics]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful tipps (also in regards to the loader). But the example you provided does not make any sense.^^ In the useEffect you wrap the fetchInitialMapStatistics in a if case, which can never be true, if this function is not called. Listening to selectedStatistics changes wont help for that eiter.

Comment: @MarcoLe oh i see what you mean, i did not use the correct function name, so i used fetchInitialMapStatistics instead of fetchMapStatisticsById, I edited my example. of course my code snippet does not have the complete code, i assume that you already have a useEffect that calls fetchInitialMapStatistics where you set selectedStatistics to a value other than null.